# Keras Add layer and NoneType: TypeError, not subscriptable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to create an FCN for segmentation in Keras using the pretrained VGG16 model as the encoder part. Now in the decoder part I'm trying to add the output of a transposed convolutional layer to the output from an earlier layer from the VGG model.

```
x = Conv2DTranspose(layer4.output_shape[-1], 4, strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
x = Add()([x, layer4])
```

But it's throwing a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` in the build function of the `Add` layer

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-39-0915433797bf> in <module>()
      7 # add a deconvolution layer, add skip with layer 4
      8 x = Conv2DTranspose(layer4.output_shape[-1], 4, strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
----> 9 x = Add()([x, layer4])
     10 
     11 # another deconvolution layer with layer 3

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py in build(self, input_shape)
     90   def build(self, input_shape):
     91     # Used purely for shape validation.
---> 92     if not isinstance(input_shape[0], tuple):
     93       raise ValueError('A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs.')
     94     if len(input_shape) < 2:
```

I reckon it has to do with the input type of the original VGG model, which takes in batches of `[(None, None, None, 3)]` tensors. But I don't know how I should fix it.

I've tried changing the `Add` layer to a `Lambda` layer like this:

```
x = Lambda(lambda x: tf.add(x[0], x[1]))((x, layer4))
```

But `tf.add` doesn't like taking Keras layers for some reason.

Either way, what would be the best way to fix this? I could make the input shape fixed, but I thought the advantages of an FCN was that it could take in a variable input shape.

Comment: Can you share the the definition of `layer4`? How do you get it out of the VGG network?

Comment: Maybe try `shape` instead of `output_shape` : `x = Conv2DTranspose(layer4.shape[-1], 4, strides=2, padding="same", activation="relu")(x)`

Comment: The model I got through `keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False)` and `layer4` is the pooling layer for block 4, which was `base_model.get_layer('block4_pool')`

Comment: `layer4` doesn't have property `shape`. It only has `input_shape` and `output_shape`.